# Meaning of "I am excited to watch the baseball game."

Tags: grammar

> I am excited to watch the baseball game

What does this sentence mean exactly?

1. I am excited as soon as I watched the baseball game.
2. I am looking forward to watching the baseball game.
3. Either 1 or 2 according to context.
4. Either 1 or 2 according to context, but 1 is more likely than 2
5. Either 1 or 2 according to context, but 2 is more likely than 1

And I want to know the reason why you choose the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the context that determines the meaning: Is the game currently in progress?

If yes, then the person is talking about the present; if no, then they are talking about the future.

---

In all likelihood, however, that's not how somebody would actually phrase the sentence.

For the present:

> I'm excited to be watching the baseball game.

For the future:

> I'm excited I'll get to watch the baseball game. *OR*
>   I'm excited to get to watch the baseball game.